# How to display numbers in different formats depending on the user's PC language settings in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, locale

I want to display numbers in different formats depending on the user's PC language settings.

Say if my PC is set in ***English*** the number *12.3* will be displayed as *12.3* and if my PC is set in ***Italian*** the number *12.3* will be displayed as *12,3*.

I tried using **myNumber.toLocaleString()** but it is not working as expected.

I also tried using the **LOCALE_ID** and set the value in providers in ***main.ts*** file :

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: navigator.language }
```

but ***navigator.language*** returns the language of the browser, **I need the language of the user's OS**.

Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Use [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] + _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_